# Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR - SEMICOLON STRING EXTRACTION

Tags: regex, oracle, substr

I have below input and need mentioned output. How I can get it. I tried different pattern but could not get through it.

so in brief, any value having all three 1#2#3 parts(if it is present) or first value should be returned

```
2#9#;2#37#65 ->  2#37#65
2#9#;2#37#65;2#37#  -> 2#37#65 
2#9#;2#37#65;2#37#;2#37#56  -> 2#37#65 or 2#37#56
2#37#65;2#99  -> 2#37#65
3#9#;3#37#65;3#37#36;2#37#56  -> 3#37#65 or 3#37#36 or 2#37#56
2#37#;2#99#  -> 2#37 or 2#99# ( in this case any value)
```

I tried few patterns and other pattern but no help.

```
    regexp_substr('2#9#;2#37#65;2#37#','#[^;]+',1)
    SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(SUBSTR(uo_filiere,1,INSTR(uo_filiere,';',1)-1), '#[^#]+$'),2)
```

Comment: Try `REGEX_REPLACE(uo_filiere, '^(.*;)?([0-9]+(#[0-9]+){2,}).*|^([^;]+).*', '\2\4')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `REGEXP_REPLACE` here:

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(uo_filiere, '^(.*;)?([0-9]+(#[0-9]+){2,}).*|^([^;]+).*', '\2\4')
```

See the [regexp demo](https://regex101.com/r/eyzwc2/1)

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*;)?` - an optional Group 1 capturing any text and then a `;`
- `([0-9]+(#[0-9]+){2,})` - Group 2 (`\2`): one or more digits, and then two or more occurrences of `#` followed with one or more digits
- `.*` - the rest of the string
- `|` - or
- `^([^;]+).*` - start of string, Group 4 capturing one or more chars other than `;` and then any text till end of string.

The replacement is Group 2 + Group 4 values.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple-minded way to solve this. It may prove more efficient than other approaches, given the particular nature of the problem.

First, use a regular expression to find the first token that has all three parts. This part of the solution should be the most efficient approach for those strings that do have a three-part token, and it performs work that must be performed on all input strings in any case.

In the second part, wrap within `nvl` - if no three-part token is found, select the first token regardless of how many parts are present. This part uses only `substr` and `instr` in a trivial manner, so it should be very fast too.

Here's the query, run on a few more sample inputs to test those cases too.

```
with
  sample_data (uo_filiere) as (
    select '2#9#;2#37#65'                 from dual union all
    select '2#9#;2#37#65;2#37#'           from dual union all
    select '2#9#;2#37#65;2#37#;2#37#56'   from dual union all
    select '2#37#65;2#99'                 from dual union all
    select '3#9#;3#37#65;3#37#36;2#37#56' from dual union all
    select '2#37#;2#99#'                  from dual union all
    select '1#22#333'                     from dual union all
    select '33#444#'                      from dual
  )
select uo_filiere,
       nvl(regexp_substr(uo_filiere, '(;|^)(([^;#]+#){2}[^;]+)', 1, 1, null, 2)
          , substr(uo_filiere, 1, instr(uo_filiere || ';', ';') - 1)
          ) as first_value
from   sample_data
;

UO_FILIERE                    FIRST_VALUE                 
----------------------------  ----------------------------
2#9#;2#37#65                  2#37#65                     
2#9#;2#37#65;2#37#            2#37#65                     
2#9#;2#37#65;2#37#;2#37#56    2#37#65                     
2#37#65;2#99                  2#37#65                     
3#9#;3#37#65;3#37#36;2#37#56  3#37#65                     
2#37#;2#99#                   2#37#                       
1#22#333                      1#22#333                    
33#444#                       33#444#
```